# How to generate a PDE from a discrete equation in a rice-pile like model?

Tags: non-linear-systems, critical-phenomena, non-equilibrium

I am reading **Noise and dynamics of self-organized critical phenomena** by *Albert Díaz-Guilera* [Here](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.45.8551), on an extension of the rice-pile model by *Bak et al* demonstrating self-organized criticality.

Equation 1 in the paper (their main equation) which describes the energy of site $i$ at time $t$ on a lattice is

$$E(i, t+1) = [1-\Theta(E(i,t) - E_c)]E(i,t) +\sum_{NN}\Theta(E(j,t) - E_c)E(j,t) +\eta_e(i,t)$$

Where $E_c$ is a constant (the meaning of which is unimportant to my question (I think)), $\Theta$ is the step function, the sum $\sum_{NN}$ is over the nearest neighbors for whatever lattice we are considering,  and $\eta_e$ is an external random noise variable.

Later on in the paper, the authors construct a PDE representing the continuous form of the equation above. After they rescale the energy, $E-E_c \rightarrow E$, they write the following equation:

$$\frac{\partial E(\vec{r},t)}{\partial t} = \alpha\nabla^2\{\Theta(E(\vec{r},t))[E(\vec{r},t) + E_c]\} + \eta_e(\vec{r},t) + \eta_i(\vec{r},t)$$

Where they claim $\alpha$ represents *"lattice spacing, to the unit time
step, and to the fraction of energy released, and plays the
role of a diffusion constant"* They also say, *"We have introduced* $\eta_i(\vec{r}, t)$
*as an internal noise, which accounts for the removed microscopic degrees of freedom, the type of lattice, for instance"*.
I really don't understand their reasoning for the introduction of both $\eta_i$ and $\alpha$.

I just cannot see how they got the continuous equation from the discrete one. How do they come up with a $\nabla^2$? I understand that it has to come from the sum over states term, but I don't understand why it has to be a second order derivative in the continuous case. I don't intuitively/physically understand how these two equations could be equivalent. How should I be thinking about this, and how do they justify the modifications they make to find the continuous PDE?